# Loading error for office addin - sometime - error office 365 has been configured to prevent indi

Tags: office365, office-js

My office addin works good most of the time, but some time it shows error as below

Office 365 has been configured to prevent individual acquisition of office store addins

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error is an indicator that your administrator settings doesn't allow individual apps in Office 365.
Since you say that your settings has been set to prevent individual acquisition, your add-in should technically never work unless you have added it to your organisation as an administrator in which case it should always work.

If this only happens occasionally it sounds like a bug or a setting not replicating properly. I would create a ticket with Microsoft and ask their support to take a look at the issue.

Comment: it occurs occasionally on its whim :)