# office.js, which files should be included and distributed from package

Tags: office-js

we are releasing the office addin developed using officejs for our on premise customer, which may not have the internet, hence i downloaded the office package and distributing with the adding locally,

package was downloaded from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js

I see that there are lots of files in the dist folder, what files should i include.  we support only windows OS, excel in office 2016 and any client of office 365.

please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and best solution is to copy the entire folder *as is*, and reference it from there.

E.g., if your site will be running on `https://example.com/your-add-in`, have your build process copy the folder to, say, `https://example.com/your-add-in/lib/office-js`, and then have the html page reference the Office.js from `https://example.com/your-add-in/lib/office-js/office.js`.

The core `office.js` file is just a loader, it will bring in the necessary files (for the host and platform, plus localization files) as needed.  But it means that you need to copy the whole directory as is, don't try to hand-trim to just the files you think you need.

Comment: thanks for reply, its an excel addin and it would be nice if you can trim the sdk to have files related to specific client atleast like excel or outlook. its taking unnecessarily extra space in cd. this is a onprem product

Comment: hi Michael, can you help me with this another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659002/loading-error-for-office-addin-sometime-error-office-365-has-been-configured i raised on stack overflow, to tell you the truth its not a good experience to work with office.js and addins. there are some and other issues all the time. please help

Comment: @shyam_, re. unnecessary space:  it's true that the files take up space, but realistically it doesn't hog any extra bandwidth, since the files are loaded on demand.  Re. your other issue:  if you're not getting traction on StackOverflow, you can also try opening up an issue on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, it's another place that the product team is looking at (and a better place for bugs, since it means that the bugs can get assigned and triaged, and the dev team can have a back-and-forth conversation in the issue comments)